# horizontal radio group with clickable labels

Tags: html, css

This code is expected to show 2 radio buttons group where they "the group" is  shown horizontally as well as "the button to the left of the caption" but I am getting the first effect but now how can I get it so that the button icon is located to the left of their corresponding caption? Thanks

**edit**
I am not using bootstrap up the html chain.

[image]

```css
.list-item {
    margin: 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
      <div class="list-item">
        {{> sub}}
      </div>

<template name="sub">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" />
    My caption 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" />
    My caption 2
  </label>
</template>
```

Comment: The sample you provided is incomplete. Are you using bootstrap ? fiddle may be more helpful for us to give answer

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja How do I know I am using bootstrap?

Comment: Your example doesn't run... I don't understand and therefore I don't know if the image is what you have or what you want... be more clear, use punctuation, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe?

```css
.list-item {
    margin: 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
Vertical <br>

<div class="list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" /> My caption 1 
  </label>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" /> My caption 2 
  </label>
</div>

Horizontal <br>

<div class="list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" /> My caption 1 
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" /> My caption 2 
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input to position:absolute; and set a padding-left on the label, it works wonders :)

Edit: you might have to set position relative on the labels.